# Selected Value in drop down, not showing as Selected in IE After Struts Form Validation/Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, struts-1

I am a new Junior java/jsp/ aspiring Full stack developer. I have a problem that I am facing in that, I have a Struts 1.3 jsp form with about 10 input fields, one of these fields is a Select Drop down, that is dynamically generated using Struts 1.3. So after a value is selected in the drop down, and Form is SUBMITTED for form/fields validation and there are some other Empty input fields so form is reshown with Error msgs, the Selected Value in the drop down is not shown as SELECTED anymore. This JSP with Struts Tag library page works fine in Chrome and Firefox(still shows as selected after Form Submit) but in Internet Explorer 11 it is not showing as selected.
I checked the html source code generated and it is shown as Selected, yet does not show in IExplorer. Mind you this field is hidden initially using jquery and only after a ajax call/webservice receives a token, are the rest of the form shown/visible.
Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.Also include code and identify the area which is causing problem. Include and error log that you are seeing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.